# Android: Cannot resolve constructor 'Date()'

Tags: android

I'm getting this error "Cannot resolve constructor 'Date()'" and i don't know why.

If someone could explain why i'm getting it, i would be grateful.

Thank you

Code:

```
/** Create a File for saving an image or video */
    private  File getOutputMediaFile(){
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/data/"
                + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                + "/Files");

        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        String mImageName="camera_wiki"+ timeStamp +".jpg";
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + mImageName);
        return mediaFile;
    }
```

Comment: Which line is it? I don't see any `Data()` usage.

Comment: Opps, my mistake. I meant 'date()' I've corrected it in the question now.

Comment: Please make sure you're using `java.util.Date`, not `java.sql.Date` class for example.

Comment: Thank you very much! Working now.

Comment: glad it worked. Do you mind if I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue is resolved by using a correct `Date` class: `java.util.Date`.